# What is the difference between :include and :through options in rails associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, model-associations

I don't understand in which case I should use the :include option instead of the :through option ?

For instance I can write my models like this :

```
Class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, :include => :line_items
end

class Order < Active Record::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :line_items
end

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
end
```

Or I can write them like this :

```
Class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  has_many  :lineitems, :through => :orders
end

class Order < Active Record::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :line_items
end

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
end
```

Thanks to clarify what practice match which option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to understand the difference after reading thoroughly the [api doc of associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/clases/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html). A specially the following sections : **Association join model** and **Eager loading of associations**

In fact they have to do with two completely different concepts :

**:through** option allows you to build **shortcuts in your code**.
In my above (question) example, I can read a LineItem collection with the following instruction :

```
@customer.lineitems
```

instead of

```
@customer.orders.lineitems
```

The **caveats** is that such attribute is **read only !**.

========

**:include** option allows you to **reduce the number of queries** generated within your database when you access different attributes/methods.

With :include in my association, the following code generates **one** query in my DB :

```
@customer.orders.lineitems
```

Without :include , it generates **two** queries in my DB

---

### Remark

As explained [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations), one can also manage to use the :include option directly in query when the model don't use such option

In my above model definition, assuming that there are 10 lineitems per order, 10 orders per customer, and 10 customers, following code would generate **101 queries**  without using :include** option in association model :
1 for .all, 1 orders per customers, and 1 lineitems per order
*(= 1 + (10 customers-orders x 10 orders-lineitems)*.

```
Customer.all.each do |customer|

  customer.orders.each do |order|
    puts "order number : " + order.number

    order.lineitems.each do |lineitem|
      puts "Item code : " + lineitem.code
    end
  end
end
```

This code would generate **12 queries**  with **includes** used directely :
1 for .first and 1 at the same time for gathering order_id and referenced orders, and 1 .lineitems for each of the 10 orders :

```
Customer.includes(:orders).each do |customer|

  customer.orders.each do |order|
    puts "order number : " + order.number

    order.lineitems.each do |lineitem|
      puts "Item code : " + lineitem.code
    end
  end
end
```

*The orders collection would have been retrieved at the same time with the customers collection (with a LEFT OUTER JOIN sql query).*